# Enclosing a single quote in Awk

Tags: awk

I currently have this line of code, that needs to be increased by one every-time in run this script. I would like to use awk in increasing the third string (570).

```
'set t 570'
```

I currently have this to change the code, however I am missing the closing quotation mark. I would also desire that this only acts on this specific (above) line, however am unsure about where to place the syntax that awk uses to do that.

```
awk '/set t /{$3+=1}  1' file.gs >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file.gs
```

Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sub()` to perform a replacement on the string itself:

```
$ awk '/set t/ {sub($3+0,$3+1,$3)} 1' file
'set t 571'
```

This looks for the value in `$3` and replaces it with itself +1. To avoid replacing all of `$3` and making sure the quote persists in the string, we say `$3+0` so that it evaluates to just the number, not the quote:

```
$ echo "'set t 570'" | awk '{print $3}'
570'
$ echo "'set t 570'" | awk '{print $3+0}'
570
```

Note this would fail if the value in `$3` happens more times in the same line, since it will replace all of them.